Geometry Nodes: How to move and rotate Instances in simulation area
What is the reason, why this cylinders aren't rotating correctly while moving into the y-direction.
As soon as I add instance rotation to them, they don't rotate around their local center and the movement behaves strange.
What's wrong here, please?
I want to move them into a direction while they are rotating. Every cyclinder have to rotate around its local center.
Thank you



I would recommend just multiplying your rotate and translate vectors by the instance ID with an ID node. Rather than using a repeat zone. Much simpler and I think will solve your problem.

Thank you. But I need it in a simulation zone.

You simply have to disable Local Space right here :

You don't want the translation to rely on the local axis of each instance. Instead, you want to move them in a global space.
This is pretty much the same as local and global axis in the viewport : one is rotating with the object, the other is the global set of axis as the ones you see in the viewport.

Thank you. Do you know how to move the instances locally (along the source mesh normals) and still rotate them?
The problem is: As soon as I switch the Local Space for translation off, the Instances rotate right, but are not moving along their local coordinates.

That's what you have with Local Space on. I'm not sure what you mean.

I've placed another question here. It describes my problem well:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/322608/geometry-nodes-how-to-rotate-instances-while-they-are-moving-along-surface-norm
