Geometry nodes: How to rotate instances while they are moving along surface normals?
In this example the cylinders are moving along the surface normals.
How to rotate them around their local origin, while they are moving away / changing their position?
Just rotating the instances is not working right. See Rotate Instances Node.
What's wrong here?
It have to work inside the simulation, please.



I've got a solution by a friend of mine and would like to share it with you.
Sometimes you get into a "nodes tunnel" when trying to achieve something new...
I completely overlooked that it's also possible to provide dynamic values outside a loop.


Indeed. Remember everything before a Simulation Zone is locked at frame 1 and never use again. Instead it uses the output of the zone from last frame.
